# How to set Default Java version on windows 10?

Tags: java, environment-variables, version, javac

I had installed **java v 1.8** on Windows 10 for years. **JAVA_HOME** and **Path** variables were updated. Then I installed Java 18 today. Did update JAVA_HOME and Path variables according to it.

When I execute `java -version` command it returns the correct version **(v18)**.

Next, I installed java **v11** and updated **JAVA_HOME** and **Path** variables for **v11**. but when I execute  `java -version` it returned **v18 as result**.

Then I **uninstalled v18 from the control panel** and executed the same command. Then I returned the correct value. v11

1. Why did `java -version` return latest version **(v18)** even I have updated **JAVA_HOME** and **Path** variables for **v11** ?
2. Where is this information saved on PC?

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
where Java
```

Make sure that this returns the path to your Java version you want. Should return something like:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10+9\bin\java.exe
```

If not then the environment variables were not set correctly.
Make sure that your JAVA_HOME is pointing to the instillation folder, and the path to the \bin folder.

Hope this helps!